# STS, running any of the Guide projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

1. I install Spring Toolsuite.
2. I go to New -> Import Getting Started project.
3. I choose the 'Building a RESTful Web Service' one. Download only the 'complete' project, select maven and not to open the site.

Now what on earth to I have to do to launch it? Right-click on the project, run as, run on server, shows 'The selection cannot be run on any server'.

I have gone through loads of posts trying to find out what else I can do, done maven clean, maven install, changed the JRE Environment, nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Running a `maven clean` or `maven install` will only update the dependencies of the project (for instance, bring in Spring and its child dependencies, loggers, etc. specified in the `pom.xml` file).

To run the project right click on the class with the `@SpringBootApplication`
 annotation (it will likely be the one with a `main` method in it, that's the one you want!).  Then select 'Run as->Java Application'.

Comment: OK that did not exactly work but it led me in the right direction. It worked when I selected the class as you said, but  'Run as->Spring Boot App'. 'Run as->Java Application' did not. No clear documentation about these things is quite frustrating as the guides on spring.io assume a lot and don't tell you how to start the project you just created.

Answer (score 1):

First a disclaimer. This answer applies to most of the guides. But there may be some to which it doesn't apply, because there's such a diversity of guides available.

Assuming you are trying a 'typical' guide which does something in the context of a web-app... then read on.

The reason that you can not run a guide with "Run On Server" is because of spring-boot adheres to the slogan of "Make Jar not War". The guide sample code are not things you deploy on a server (i.e war) but are standalone Java apps (i.e. jar) which **contain** their own embedded servlet container (if they need one). That means running them is really quite simple. Just find the 'main' method/class in the guide and use Eclipse "Run As >> Java Application".

There's also a convenient alias in STS called "Run As >> Spring Boot App" which does pretty much the same thing but gives you a few extra bells and whistles in the launch configuration editor.

Also... you don't really have to go look for the main method yourself because the "Run As >> Spring Boot App" knows how to find it in most cases. So clicking project and "Run As >> Spring Boot App" should do the trick.